# useEffect called twice after passing multiple arguments

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I am  using react hooks useEffect for loading data in my component. I am facing strange problem, In my case If there is some data coming from backend, I have to bind that to my component, otherwise default value should be bound to my component. Unfortunately my code is working perfectly fine most of the times but showing default value at times even though data is coming from backend. Actually it is loading two times and data is getting overwritten by default value sometimes.

I have tried many ways but failed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getReadJson();
    getReadAudio();

        if (readJson) {
          const Jparse = JSON.parse(readJson);
          console.log("Jparse", Jparse);
          Jparse &&
            Jparse.map((jsondata) => {
              peaksInstance.segments.add({
                startTime: parseFloat(jsondata.startTime),
                endTime: parseFloat(jsondata.endTime),
                labelText: jsondata.segmentData,
                editable: false,
                speakerId: jsondata.speakerId,
              });
              peaksInstance.points.add({
                time: parseFloat(jsondata.endTime),
                editable: false,
              });
            });
        }
        if (peaksInstance.segments._segments.length == 0) {
          debugger;
          const endTime = peaksInstance.player.getDuration();
          peaksInstance.segments.add({
            startTime: 0,
            endTime: endTime,
            labelText: "",
            editable: false,
            speakerId: "",
          });
        }
   
  }, [getReadJson, readJson, getReadAudio, readAudio]);
```

I am new to react hooks. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way temporarily.

```
var isEffect = false
useEffect(() => {
  if (isEffect) { isEffect = false; return;}

  ... code .....
  
  isEffect = true; 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const isFirstRender = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
   if (isFirstRender.current) {

      code...

   }
}, []);
```